# Stuck on GNU GRUB Version 2.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, bootloader

I downloaded and dual booted Ubuntu with IOS (Catalina) for a project and to learn Linux. I put it on a separate partition from my Catalina container and only used about 10% of my drive. I didn’t need it anymore and deleted the partition and when I tried to get back in to the IOS partition it’s showing me the grub screen. I’ve tried to change the boot drive and the iOS drives aren’t showing. Then I went into recovery and it’s only booting from the 50 GBs that used to be Ubuntu. Inspecting the drive it shows that everything is still allocated but I cannot get into it.

How do I fix it?

Comment: You needed to make your wanted OS own the boot process (*the last installed OS will own this process unless you change it*) before you deleted your unwanted OS.  This is Ubuntu support; you've removed your Ubuntu system (*boot was in `/boot/grub` of the Ubuntu partition, which is deleted from your description thus you've grub rescue; grub is a bootloader installed by Ubuntu & other OSes but a GNU program, not Ubuntu directly*). You now need to boot your wanted IOS recovery media, and execute the IOS commands that make it take ownership of the boot process (*what you should have done first*)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was unaware of those extra steps. Do you happen to have any resources on how tho go about doing those things?